# Como iterar de forma correta todos os registros de uma estrutura com multiplos níveis de profundidade em Rust?

Tags: struct, iterator, rust

Gostaria de saber como iterar de forma correta em Rust todos os resultados contidos em uma estrutura de dados disposta assim:

```
struct Node {
    id: i64,
    nodes: Vec<Node>
}
```

Onde os registros inseridos nessa estrutura possuem varios níveis de profundidade. Algo como:

```
{id: 1, nodes: [
    {id: 2, nodes: [ 
        {id: 3, nodes: []}, 
        {id: 4, nodes: []},
        {id: 5, nodes: [
            {id: 6, nodes: []},
            {id: 7, nodes: [
                {id: 8, nodes: []},
                {id: 9, nodes: []}
            ]}
        ]}
    ]}
]};
```

Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Eu criei uma simples função recursiva para lidar com o problema. E tudo está ok agora. Eu não sei qual foi o meu equívoco ontem para criar esse tópico, mas creio ter sido algum problema de tipagem do Rust.

O problema real que eu enfrentava era um pouco diferente (a estrutura mencionada) da pergunta feita, mas a essência era a mesma. E aqui está a minha pequena solução:

```
use std::vec::Vec;

struct Node
{
       id: i64,
       nodes: Vec<Node>,
       focused: bool
}

struct Controller
{
    focused: i32
}

impl Controller
{
    fn get_focused(&mut self) -> i32
    {
        let nodes: Node = ....; // código suprimido. representado pelo JSON object acima citado, com adição do membro 'focused' na estrtura.

        for node in nodes.iter()
        {
            self.focused = self.node_iterator(node);
        }
        self.focused
    }

    fn node_iterator(&self, node: Node) -> i32
    {
        let mut focused: i32 = 0;

        if node.nodes.len() > 0
        {
            for n in node.nodes.iter()
            {
                if n.nodes.len() > 0
                {
                    focused = self.node_iterator(n);
                    if focused > 0
                    {
                        return focused;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if n.focused == true
                    {
                        focused = n.id as i32;
                        return focused;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}


fn main()
{
    let mut controller = Controller{focused: 0};

    controller.get_focused();

    println!("{}", controller.focused);
}
```

Se alguém souber de alguma forma mais elegante para lidar com esse problema, fique a vontade para compartilhar.

Comment: Minha mesma pergunta feita no SO inglês aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797743/how-to-correctly-iterate-all-records-of-a-multi-level-depth-structure-in-rust . Vale ressaltar a resposta dada pelo @Shepmaster em seu último comentário.

Answer (score 0):

Caso a ideia seja simplesmente iterar, acho que uma solução mais simples é mais válida.

Dada a modulagem proposta:

```rust
struct Node {
    id: i64,
    nodes: Vec<Node>,
}
```

Podemos simplesmente construir uma função que recebe um nó (ou uma lista de nós, para dar suporte a listas top level) e age sobre aquele nó. Em seguida a função deve seguir para a lista de nós interna ao nó atual, repetindo o processo.

Um fluxograma representando essa ideia é exposto a seguir:

[image: Fluxograma da ideia proposta]

O proposto é, então, uma função recursiva. Ela poderia ser representada da seguinte forma:

```rust
fn parse_nodes(nodes: &Vec<Node>) {
    nodes.iter()
        .map(|ref node| {
            let id = node.id;
            let len = node.nodes.len();
            println!("id: {} - child nodes: {}", id, len);

            parse_nodes(&node.nodes);
        })
        .count();
}
```

Se não nos importarmos ou não pudermos aceitar listas como argumento inicial da função, podemos construir a função da seguinte forma:

```rust
fn parse_node(node: &Node) {
    let id = node.id;
    let len = node.nodes.len();
    println!("id: {} - child nodes: {}", id, len);

    node.nodes
        .iter()
        .map(|ref node| parse_node(&node))
        .count();
}
```

Com essas duas soluções conseguimos resolver o problema proposto, de *iterar uma estrutura como a exposta*.

Ambas as soluções poderiam utilizar elementos de paralelismo para diminuir o tempo de execução do *parser*. Esta resposta não tratará dessa abordagem, entretanto. Para mais informações a respeito, uma boa referência é o capítulo 16 do livro *The Rust Programming Language* ([link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch16-00-concurrency.html)).